# Searching multidimensional array subarray

Tags: php, arrays

hi i have following array

```
$langarr[0][0]  =    gb
$langarr[0][1]  =    1
$langarr[1][0]  =    de
$langarr[1][1]  =    2
$langarr[2][0]  =    fr
$langarr[2][1]  =    3
$langarr[3][0]  =    it
$langarr[3][1]  =    5
```

Now i wanna search to unset like

```
if(($keyy = array_search('de', $langarr[][0])) !== false) {
    unset($langarr[$keyy]);
}
```

So i wanna search in the `langarr[any][0]` and if matched I want to delete the whole dataset like `unset($langarr[X]);`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
$langarr = array();

$langarr[0][0]  =    "gb";
$langarr[0][1]  =    "1";
$langarr[1][0]  =    "de";
$langarr[1][1]  =    "2";
$langarr[2][0]  =    "fr";
$langarr[2][1]  =    "3";
$langarr[3][0]  =    "it";
$langarr[3][1]  =    "5";
```

// Get the key of search array

```
$value = recursive_array_search("de",$langarr);
```

// print the key

```
print_r($value);
```

// unset the array "de" which has key "1"

```
unset($langarr[$value]);
```

// print the resultant array

print_r($langarr);

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). It takes a (anonymous) function as the second argument. The function itself receives an array element as its argument. If that function returns `false`, the array element is removed from the array.

So to take your example, if `$needle` is 'de', the subarray is removed.

```
$langarr = array(
  array('gb', 1),
  array('de', 2),
);

$needle = 'de';
$langarr = array_filter($langarr, function($row) use($needle) {
  return ($row[0] != $needle);
});
```

[Online test](https://eval.in/313790)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$langarr[0][0]  =    "gb";
$langarr[0][1]  =    1;
$langarr[1][0]  =    "de";
$langarr[1][1]  =    2;
$langarr[2][0]  =    "fr";
$langarr[2][1]  =    3;
$langarr[4][0]  =    "it";
$langarr[4][1]  =    4;
print_r($langarr);
foreach($langarr as $key=>$data){
    if($data[0]=='de'){
        unset($langarr[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($langarr);
?>
```